# php, jquery, sql. form validation

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, validation, post

Basically I have a page that displays a seating plan using check boxes. These check boxes can be ticked to represent the seat being booked. I also have a text input where names are entered for the bookings, these forms are then posted to the next page to work out what check boxes are selected and save them in the database. This is some of the code:

```
        title>School Hall</title>

<script>


        function confirmReservation() {

        var selectedList = getSelectedList('Confirm Reservation');

        if (selectedList) {
            if (confirm('Do you want to CONFIRM this Reservation :  ' + selectedList + '?')) { 
                document.forms[0].statusA.value=0;
                document.forms[0].statusB.value=1;
                document.forms[0].previousPage.value='schoolHall';
                document.forms[0].action='bookingQueries.php';      
                document.forms[0].submit();
            } else {
                clearSelection();
            }
        }
    }



        function cancelReservation() {

        var selectedList = getSelectedList('cancel Reservation');

        if (selectedList) {
            if (confirm('Do you want to CANCEL this Reservation :  ' + selectedList + '?')) { 
                document.forms[0].statusA.value=1;
                document.forms[0].statusB.value=0;
                document.forms[0].previousPage.value='schoolHall';
                document.forms[0].action='bookingQueries.php';
                document.forms[0].submit();
            } else {
                clearSelection();
            }
        }
    }




    function getSelectedList(actionSelected) {

        // get selected list
        var obj = document.forms[0].elements;
        var selectedList = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            if (obj[i].checked && obj[i].name == 'seats[]') {
                selectedList += obj[i].value + ', ';
            }
        }

        // no selection error
        if (selectedList == '') {
            alert('Please select a seat ');
            return false;
        } else {
            return selectedList;
        }

    }




    function validateForm()
    {
    var x=document.forms["0"]["fname"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("First name must be filled out");
      return false;
      }
    }


</script>



</head>
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0"  >
<table>
<tr><td width="100%" align="left" id='table-2'>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="previousPage" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="statusA" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="statusB" value=""/>
</tr>
<table>
<tr><td width="100%" align=left" id='table-2'>
<INPUT Type="BUTTON" VALUE="Home Page" ONCLICK="window.location.href='/final/homePage.php'" align='lef'>
<INPUT Type="BUTTON" VALUE="Bookings" ONCLICK="window.location.href='/final/schoolHallBookings.php'"> 


<?php


 // Connection
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!con)
{
die('Could not connect:' . mysql_error());
}

 mysql_select_db("systemDatabase",$con); // Connection to DB

 echo '<br>';  

 echo '<font face="Trebuchet MS" color="Black" size="9" >School Hall </font>';


 $query = "SELECT * from schoolHall order by rowId, columnId"; // Create Select Query
 $result = mysql_query($query); // Retrieve all data from query and hold in $result
 $prevRowId = null;
 $seatColor = null;
 $tableRow = false;


 echo "<table align='center' id='table-2'"; // Create table
 while (list($rowId, $columnId, $status, $updatedby, $firstName, $lastName) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) //      Itterates through fetched data
 {
if ($prevRowId != $rowId) 
{
    if ($rowId != 'A') 
    {
        echo "</tr></table></td>";
        echo "\n</tr>";
    }
    $prevRowId = $rowId;
    echo "\n<tr><td align='center'><table class='center' border='1' cellpadding='15' cellspacing='8'        align='center' id='table-2' ><tr>";
} 
else 
{
    $tableRow = false;
}
if ($status == 0) 
{
    $seatColor = "lightgreen"; // Available
}
 else 
{
    $seatColor = "red"; // Booked
}

echo "\n<td bgcolor='$seatColor' align='center'>";
echo "$rowId$columnId";
if ($status == 0 || ($status == 1)) {
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='seats[]' value='$rowId$columnId' align='center'></checkbox>"; //   Create Checkboxes giving value RowId, ColumnId
}


    }

 echo "</tr></table></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
 echo "</table>";

 // Con close
 mysql_close();
 ?> 



  <table width='100%' border='0'>
<tr><td align='right'>
  &nbsp;
 &nbsp; First Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
 &nbsp; Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname">
</td>
<td><td align='left'>


</td>
 <td><td align ='right'>

    &nbsp;<input type='button' value='Confirm Reservation' onclick='confirmReservation()'/>  
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><td align='left'>



</td>
<td><td align='left'>


</td>
 <td align='right'>
    &nbsp;<input type='button' value=' Cancel Reservation' onclick='cancelReservation()'>
   </td>
 </table>
 </td></tr>
 <tr><td width="100%" align="center">


 </td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td width="100%" align="center">
<table border="1" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="4" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor='lightgreen'>Available</td>
        <td bgcolor='red'>Unavailable</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td width="100%" align="center">
</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
```

Is there any way i can incorporate validation with my current code? I need the names text checked to make sure there is actually a name entered. This needs to happen before the next page is accessed. Any ideas?

Comment: please, post your html to show your named text an why getSelectedList take variable without use it , and you don't remove the last comma.

Comment: Sorry what was that about selectedList? added the html code

Comment: function getSelectedList(actionSelected) , where you use actionSelected and after finish your loop selectedList will be '1,3,6,' , are you want the last comma

Comment: Sorry i dont understand, selected list works exactly how it is supposed to. It checks whether checkboxes are checked or not. It works perfectly fine, thats not what this question is about?

Comment: I'm confused, do you need the `<input name="fname" />` to be validated?

Comment: yeah i need it to check whether its empty or not, problem is that it gets posted with the confirm reservation() function so im not sure how to do it?

Comment: is it suppose each row contain checkbox and two inputs for fname and lname and you need validation for if checkbox is checked the fname and lname must be filled in?

Comment: ermm I need validation for the fname and lname must be filled in for the checkboxes to be submitted yes!

Comment: I don't see them being "Filled in" anywhere though - where are they being assigned values?

Comment: theres the full code for that page, the fname and lname get sent to the next page when the form is submitted, they are assigned to variables there which are used in an sql UPDATE query to save into databse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first add ids to your text input:

```
<table width='100%' border='0'>
  <tr>
    <td align='right'>
      &nbsp;
      &nbsp; First Name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"/>
      &nbsp; Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"/>
    </td>
  <td>
  <td align='left'>

function getSelectedList(actionSelected) {
    // get selected list
    var obj = document.forms[0].elements;
    var selectedList = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if (obj[i].checked && obj[i].name == 'seats[]') {
            selectedList += obj[i].value + ', ';
        }
    }
    var fname = document.getElementById('fname');
    var lname = document.getElementById('lname');
    // no selection error
    if (selectedList == '') {
        alert('Please select a seat ');
        return false;
    } else if (actionSelected.beginsWith('Confirm') &&  (fname .value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').length == 0 || /[0-9]/.test(fname))) {
        alert('Please Enter valid first name.');
        return false;
    } else if (actionSelected.beginsWith('Confirm') && (lname.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').length == 0 || /[0-9]/.test(lname))) {
        alert('Please Enter valid last name.');
        return false;
    } else {
        return selectedList;
    }
}
```

Comment: genius ! that works perfectly, how would i make this not take numbers also?

Comment: this actually conflicts with another function of mine, cancel reservation(), i do not want it to require a name for that, how could i go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Working example

http://jsfiddle.net/

The below example demonstrates how you can pass a value to the function `checkInput` and it will determine whether or not it is a valid input - the function uses jQuery but you can do it whthout jQuery too.

Demo HTML:

```
<form>
    <input id="first-name" value="some value" />
    <input id="last-name" value="" />
</form>
```

JS Function (goes with HTML demo):

```
function checkInput(fieldID){
    var isValid = true;

    if($("#" + fieldID).val() == ''){
        isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;

}


$(document).ready(function(){
    if(!checkInput("first-name")){
        alert("error found with first name");
    }
    if(!checkInput("last-name")){
        alert("error found with last name");
    }
});
```